# How do I start using my repository locally and on Github?

Tags: git, github

So:

1) I have created my account on github and I've created a repository there.

2) I have the keys to access the repository from my dev machine to github, using SSH, so that my local repository is synchronized with the remote one hosted on github once I do, push or pull.

But, I'm not understanding how will all this start.

I have my local files on this dev computer and from there I do:

3) git init

then

4) git add

and then I 5) commit that project to my LOCAL repository.

Once this is done, then I will 6) push this to github repository.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: Did you read the github guides? (http://help.github.com/set-up-git-redirect)

Comment: That's right. Is there some step that isn't working for you?

Comment: @Greg he never said he added a remote, see my answer

Comment: @All thanks for your comments and answers. :) Can't wait to see it work. I'm trying all at once, git capistrano zend tool, local repository, local host, shared... uaaaahhh omfg! :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That's basically correct, yes. To explain what each thing is doing...

1. `git init` basically says, "Hey, I want a repository here." You only will have to do this once per repository.
2. After that, you will want to add a remote, which GitHub probably told you to do by using `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repository` This allows you to push to a remote. You will only have to do this once as well.
3. After that, use `git add` to add your changes, or "stage them". You can use `git add -i` for a bit of a more interactive experience.
4. Use `git commit -m 'message'` to commit locally.
5. Then use `git push origin master` This says, "Push all of the commits to the remote origin, under master.
6. If you make changes from another machine, or someone else makes changes, you can use `git pull` to get them from the remote.

You might want to consider reading [ProGit](http://progit.org/book/) - it's free online and is a wealth of information. There you can learn more about features like branching, merging, etc.

Comment: ProGit is really REALLY a good reading. I had start already but those specifc details, about how all this starts, in the same way that I redirect my doubt here weren't clear to me. Hence, my doubt, that you have, successfully answered. :)

Comment: This almost worked for me. When I say "git push origin master" it says "blahblahblah.git" doesn't exist and hangs up. Note the absence of a slash. When I sayd "git init," it created "blahblahblah/.git" -- note the slash. ".git" is a directory full of appropriate info, so it looks like the adds and commits all worked, but I can't get the push to work. Stuck! Lost :(

Comment: I needed to say `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository.git`

Answer (score 4):

You're missing one step: somewhere before the last step, you need to do a `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame` so that Git knows where to push your repo when you say `git push origin master`. Otherwise, you've got it! You may want to check your work with `git diff` before you commit, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to do an: `git push origin master` you can find details here: http://programertools.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-use-github.html