# Synchronize project between systems with GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am working on a website from my laptop and my home computer. Previously I was just downloading with FTP, but that got kind of complicated since I started using GitHub.

How do I get the changes I committed from computer A up to GitHub on to computer B?

Comment: On a side note, if you wanted a very simple method.. use Dropbox - it's worked wonders for me, and it's all automated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I start using my repository locally and on Github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437521/how-do-i-start-using-my-repository-locally-and-on-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Former SVN user I guess?
You don't "commit" from Computer A to github, you "push" from Computer A to github.
Similarly, you can pull from Computer B to your computer by using `git pull`.

If you haven't, you need to clone the github repository first using `git clone`

Comment: Ok... chosing `git` is a very good decision though. Thank god you don't have to use SVN or CVS, they are a real pain.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
git pull
```

See [the manual for pull](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)